# Why do I convert map to json, map includes list values which is nothing after converting to json

Tags: json, list, go

```
func Test_JsonTtransfer(t *testing.T) {

    uid := "306"
    phoneList := list.New()
    phoneList.PushBack("18513622928")
    fmt.Println("phoneList=======", phoneList.Len())


    jsonPhoneList, err := json.Marshal(phoneList)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("jsonPhoneList=======", string(jsonPhoneList))

    idCardList := list.New()
    idCardList.PushBack("230405197608040640")

    request := make(map[string]interface{})
    request["uid"] = uid

    request["phones"] = phoneList

    request["id_cards"] = idCardList

    json, err := json.Marshal(request)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("json=======", json)
    fmt.Println("json=======", string(json))
}
```

Output:

> D:/Sys/server/Go\bin\go.exe test -v golang-test/com/http/test -run ^Test_JsonTtransfer$
>   phoneList======= 1
>   jsonPhoneList======= {}
>   json======= [123 34 105 100 95 99 97 114 100 115 34 58 123 125 44 34 112 104 111 110 101 115 34 58 123 125 44 34 117 105 100 34 58 34 51 48 54 34 125]
>   json======= {"id_cards":{},"phones":{},"uid":"306"}
>   ok     golang-test/com/http/test   0.482s

Phones should be list values, but nothing. Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Because the [List](https://godoc.org/container/list#List) type has no exported fields and the type does not implement the [Marshaler](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshaler)interface, List values always marshal to the text `{}`.

A simple fix is to use a slice instead of a list:

```
var phoneList []string
phoneList = append(phoneList, "18513622928")
fmt.Println("phoneList=======", len(phoneList)
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/gUrxjn27_D)

Comment: sorry，your answer is great, but i do not care the button for down. i  agree your idea.

Comment: i just start use this stackoverflow,    i should Adopt your suggestion，but now  for my negligence， the  administrator help me cancel my error elect